# Error deploying grails on Wildfly 10

Tags: grails, jboss

- Grails Version: 2.3.11
- Java Version: 1.8.91
- JBoss AS Version: 10.1.0
- Gradle Version: 3.2.1

Grails application build runs successfully. But when I deploy build on JBoss Wildfly 10 it does not deployed and failed with error. Below is stacktrace printed on console.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:24)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        ... 19 more
```

I have deleted gradle cache from directory `<user_home>/.gradle/` and grails cache from `<user_home>/.grails/2.3.11` and build the project. But getting same error.

Any idea/suggestion where this is going wrong?

Comment: What's your line 24 in your BoostStrap.groovy?

Comment: Line #24: `realTimeViewerService.start();`

Comment: `realTimeViewerService` is a Grails service class and is not null.